# How to parse a Haskell file without making it a module

Tags: parsing, haskell

I've just started writing a Haskell program to golf Haskell programs (minimize the number of characters), but I'm running into a parsing problem. When I use the `parseModule` function from `Language.Haskell.Parser`, it adds a module declaration to the file.  Obviously, this is not what I want because it adds unnecessary characters!

So, for a program containing some code represented by `...`, the output would be this.

```
module Main (main) where { main = do {  ...  }}
```

Is there a simple solution to this, or would I have to modify the `HsModule` returned from `parseModule` to output a file without a module declaration?

Comment: Can't you just subtract that character count from the result?

Comment: That's one way to do it, but what about when the input file is already a module? I felt that there might be an elegant solution that covers all cases that I just wasn't seeing.